# Python: Email Multiple Email Addresses Individually Tailored Information stored in MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql

I am looking to email 3 individuals a separate email of relevant information to that specific individual in Python.

John is in charge of "Cars", Bob in charge of "Trucks", Fred in charge of "Vans", etc....

These email addresses are stored in a table named 'Manager' in MySQL Database 'Stats'.  The relevant information to each Manager is stored in the same MySQL Database 'Stats' but in a table named 'Information'

**Manager Table:**

[image: First Table]

**Information Table:**

[image: Second Table]

What is the best approach from here to email John the Customer Comments from his department Cars?

This is my very basic starting point:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='root', db='stats')
cur = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Information")
result_set = cur.fetchall()
for row in result_set:
    print("%s, %s" % (row["Department"], row["CustomerComment"]))
```

Comment: I'm unclear what your question is? What is wrong with your current approach and why do you import SQLAlchemy and never use it?

Comment: I want to email John, Bob and Fred individually with their own Customer Comment.  I've edited my post to remove the import of sqlalchemy

Comment: You need some kind of email client. Your SQL query is too quick to really care, unless I'm misunderstanding. That's where the focus of your research should be; it's leaving things a bit broad atm.

Comment: I agree.  It's very broad as I am looking for resources to enlighten me :)  I am familiar with sending emails in general with smtplib however lack the knowledge to loop through email addresses within a MySQL table.